# MVC6 View Referencing issue due to routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc

In my solution I have at the root level a Controller, Views Folder each of these have a Home Folder with an Home Controller with Index method and the view folder with an index view (default MVC setup). At the root level I have introduced an Areas folder then in here I have created another Folder for the area then folders for controllers and views. Home controller with index method and views folder with index view.
 it all builds fine, but I receive the following error:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> VisualJobs.Controllers.HomeController.Index (VisualJobs)
>   VisualJobs.Areas.Recruiter.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (VisualJobs) VisualJobs.Areas.Jobs.Controllers.HomeController.Index
>   (VisualJobs)

in my Configuration file I have:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "areaRoute",
           template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

Folder structure:

```
 Areas -->Candidate-->Controllers
                      Shared
                      ViewModels
                      Views 
 Areas -->Recruiter-->Controllers
                      Shared
                      ViewModels
                      Views 
Controllers 
Views
```

Comment: Can you show up your folder structure here?

Comment: @SmitPatel I've updated the main question. I couldn't get it to format in a comment correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because you have not decorated your area controller classes with the Area attribute.  Something like this.

```
[Area("Recruiter")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

You also need _ViewImports.cshtml and _ViewStart.cshtml in the Views folder of your area.